# salesforce: I want to know what is wrapper class in salesforce and a scenario of using wrapper class with simple exapmle.?

Tags: salesforce, wrapper

I want to know what is wrapper class in salesforce and a scenario of using wrapper class with simple exapmle.??

Answer (score 0):

I would say check it here and RTFM:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class

> A wrapper or container class is a class, a data structure, or an
>   abstract data type whose instances are collections of other objects.
>   In Apex and Visualforce this type of class can be extremely useful but
>   to a new developer the talk of wrapper classes may fly right over your
>   head, it definitely did for me. Here I will supply a simple demo of
>   how wrapper classes can be used.